# R weekdays(Sys.Date()) - Cannot figure out what causes this behavior

Tags: r, weekday

I am in Russia, I send reports on Monday using Windows scheduler. 'понедельник' stands for Monday in Russian.

In fact I face a strange behavior of weekdays(Sys.Date()) that differs based on how I call it. When calling from RStudio IDE or from R console this `if(` statement returns TRUE today (which is monday) as expected, but when calling this script from the command line or using a scheduler, the condition returns FALSE. I am really confused. I cannot debug it.

```
week_day_send <- F

print(weekdays(Sys.Date()))

if(
     weekdays(Sys.Date()) == 'понедельник'
)
{

     week_day_send <- T

     message('sending weekly reports')

}
```

My locale is:

```
> Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
[1] "Russian_Russia.1251"
```

Comment: I guess it might be a problem of encoding. However, one shouldn't rely on `weekdays` since it's local dependent. At least, don't hardcode the value. Define something like `monday <- weekdays(someKnownMonday)` and then compare `weekdays(Sys.Date())` with `monday`.

Comment: try using wday function of lubridate

Comment: OK, nicola, thank you. I made it. monday <- weekdays(as.Date("2019-03-04")) works from both IDE and command line, so it is solved I think. I will later lubridate too, thanks a lot! Ghh, such a buggy bug.

Comment: @Hunaidkhan I used lubridate to get week days in my other report and it helped. Thank you!

Comment: your welcome @AlexeyBurnakov